# Hidden records which exceed numeric limits in Postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, precision

I have a PG DB containing mostly numeric data, where accuracy of numeric data is important so fields are typically Numeric (7,3) because the largest expected non error value is around 1300. I am importing some data which contains some records exceeding the 10^4 limit, due to sensor faults, so I have applied an error code to these values using:

```
 UPDATE schema.table1 SET fieldname1 = 3333 WHERE fieldname1 > 3333;
```

(i.e. If an operator sees 3333 in the data it is known to be an erroneous value because it is outside the normally expected range and it's known to be human applied due to the sequence which is unlikely in nature).
The success of this query was confirmed by:

```
MAX (fieldname1)
```

which returns 3333 for all fields which previously had values exceeding 3333.

This initial tidying of data was done in a temporary table with the Fields defined as Numeric (10,3), and I now need to import the data into the main table, using:

```
INSERT INTO schema.table2
(DateTime, Fieldname1)
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (DateTime)
DateTime,
Fieldname1
FROM Schema.table1
WHERE DateTime IS NOT NULL
```

But I get an error message saying 'datatype Numeric(7,3) cannot contain values exceeding 10^4' (or words to that effect).
As an experiment I tried redefining the datatypes in the temporary table as Numeric (7,3). This worked for most of the fields, but for a few fields I got the 'datatype Numeric(7,3) cannot contain values exceeding 10^4' message, implying that there is still data >10^4 despite the MAX(Fieldname1) command returning 3333. 
Tried VACUUM and ANALYZE to clean up the tables, no cigar. 
Is there a known issue here? am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Did you check MIN() as well to see whether there are negative values exceeding the limits?

Comment: `INSERT INTO schema.table ... SELECT ...  FROM Schema.table ...` You are inserting into the same table as where you are selecting from. Please post real code, and include the actual table definitions.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I think you have spotted my oversight here!